# Function for Reshape View?

Tags: view, julia

In Julia v0.5, how do you make a function which is like reshape but instead returns a view? ArrayViews.jl has a reshape_view function but it doesn't seem directly compatible with the new `view` function. I just want to `reshape` `u` to some tuple `sizeu` where I don't know the dimensions.

Comment: `reshape` seems to work fine for me for views, and returns a view. what isn't working for you exactly?

Comment: I want to reshape an array and get a view of that array out.

Comment: Ah, right, so you want to pass a *normal* array and get a view out?

Comment: Yeah, pass a normal array but a view out where the view makes it act like it's been reshaped, but without allocating.

Comment: there are no reallocations during reshaping anyway. you can confirm this with the pointer function

Comment: Oh I just verified it by saving the reshaped value to another variable, changing that variable, and watching it change the first. Wow, I never knew. I probably should've checked that... Post that as an answer so I can mark it. Simple but true.

Comment: It's not well known, but `Array` can actually be a view. Try this: 
`a = rand(6); B = reshape(a, 3, 2); push!(a, 1)` and you'll get an error that reveals this feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you reshape a 'view', the output is a reshaped 'view'.

If your initial variable is a normal array, you can convert it to a view 'on the fly' during your function call.

There are no reallocations during this operation, as per your later comment: you can confirm this with the `pointer` function. The objects aren't the same, in the sense that they are interpreted as pointers to a different 'type', but the memory address is the same.

```
julia> A = ones(5,5,5); B = view(A, 2:4, 2:4, 2:4); C = reshape(B, 1, 27);

julia> is(B,C)
false

julia> pointer(B)
Ptr{Float64} @0x00007ff51e8b1ac8

julia> pointer(C)
Ptr{Float64} @0x00007ff51e8b1ac8

julia> C[1:5] = zeros(1,5);

julia> A[:,:,2]
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```