# Why reshape() in Julia does not change the contents of an array in a function?

Tags: arrays, matrix, syntax, julia

I want to reshape a matrix inside of a function, so I "declared" an array outside of the function and used `reshape()` in the function. It doesn't really work, even though array is mutable.

```
julia> my_array = 1:10
1:10

julia> function test(array)
           array = reshape(array, 2, 5)
           println(array)
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test(my_array)
[1 3 5 7 9; 2 4 6 8 10]

julia> println(my_array)
1:10
```

Inside of the function, `my_array` has been reshaped into a 2*5 matrix, but it restores the 1:10 after executing the function.

I am wondering the reason behind that, and how can I reshape a global array inside of function?

**EDIT**: My problem is different from [variable references in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249991/variable-references-in-lisp), I know the idea of passing a copy of variable into stack. For this problem, I don't know why the specific function `reshape()` does not change array's contents, even if I pass the reference of a mutable object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable references in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249991/variable-references-in-lisp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering the reason behind that, and how can I reshape a global array inside of function?

`reshape`ing in general is not type stable if it was mutable: here you show that you change a vector into matrix, so the type would have had to change. That's why `reshape` returns instead of mutates since type-stability is so central to Julia programming.

However, `reshape` [actually returns a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777469/function-for-reshape-view/38778099), so you can check that `v = reshape(A,...)` doesn't actually copy any data: it just creates a new type which defines a new indexing scheme. Since arrays are passed by reference (i.e. by pointer), there's really no cost to returning the `reshape`d type. So to get the behavior you want without performance problems, the answer is just to catch the returned type:

```
function test(array)
  array = reshape(array, 2, 5)
  array
end
reshaped = test(array)
```

Comment: In addtion to Chris' comments, another issue is that you are passing a `UnitRange`, so that if you tried to modified the values of the passed in array after reshaping it, in that case it would not work.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://julia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/faq/#i-passed-an-argument-x-to-a-function-modified-it-inside-that-function-but-on-the-outside-the-variable-x-is-still-unchanged-why):

> Suppose you call a function like this:
>
> ```
> julia> x = 10
> 10
>
> julia> function change_value!(y)
>            y = 17
>        end
> change_value! (generic function with 1 method)
>
> julia> change_value!(x)
> 17
>
> julia> x # x is unchanged!
> 10
> ```
>
> In Julia, the binding of a variable `x` cannot be changed by passing `x`
>   as an argument to a function. When calling `change_value!(x)` in the
>   above example, `y` is a newly created variable, bound initially to the
>   value of `x`, i.e. 10; then `y` is rebound to the constant 17, while the
>   variable `x` of the outer scope is left untouched.

Thus you cannot reassign a variable by reassigning the passed value within the function.

That being said, some collections allow mutations (but still no reassignment):

```
julia> function mut(x)
       x[1] = 100
       end
mut (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> mut(a)
100

julia> a
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 100
   2
   3
```

If you want to change the array itself and get some other answer you can use a tuple to return multiple values:

```
julia> function dubSum(x)
           x = hcat(x,x)
           sum_val = sum(x)
           return (x, sum_val)
       end
dubSum (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> x, sum_val = dubSum(x)
(
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3,

12)

julia> x
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3

julia> sum_val
12
```